# GoCD run bash script on Pipeline

Tags: bash, go-cd

I got a pipeline called Funcional_Test, I'm trying to run on that pipeline a script located in this path: /home/vagrant/VirtualMachines/software_test.sh

This is te configuration:
[image]

When I run the pipeline I got these errors:
[image]

Am I missing something? What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you share the exact command you gave?

Comment: Sure: /home/vagrant/VirtualMachine/software_test.sh

Comment: I tryed to go to the path by using cd /home/vagrant/VirtualMachine/ but It gave me the error: Not a directory.

Comment: How can I change the user that runs Go-Agent in Linux?, I wanna test it.

Comment: It should be `./home/vagrant/VirtualMachine/software_test.sh`

Comment: I ran some tests and It was permissions, but right now I got a different problem, when I run the script localy It does "vagrant up" without problems " default: Importing base box 'windows10'...", but when I run it from GoCD I got the error "default: Box 'windows10' could not be found. Attempting to find and install..."

Comment: You are describing multiple problems here. I find it difficult to understand if your initial issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I'm working on those problems right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Mention /bin/sh in Command (change it depends on the script type)
Mention the script file in Arguments section in same line