# GoCD - Angular Build not able execute

Tags: angular, npm, go-cd

I am working on GoCD interface for Angular deployment configuration. I did configure `npm install` but after I am trying to execute the build command as below, but it is throwing error like

> Please make sure [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build] can be executed on this agent.

Command:

```
/usr/local/bin/ng build --configuration=qa
```

See below for the console output (it is working if I execute the above in my machine directly).

I have configured GoCD in my local mac.

```
 [go] Task: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build" --configuration=qatook: 0.5s
    Error happened while attempting to execute '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=qa'. 
    Please make sure [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build] can be executed on this agent.
    
  [Debug Information] Environment variable PATH: /usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    [go] Task status: failed, took: 0.5s
    [go] Current job status: failed
```

Comment: Please try to execute `/usr/local/bin/ng build --configuration=qa` as the `go` user on the agent. If it doesn't work without GoCD being involved, Go has nothing to do with it, and it's "just" a broken npm or ng installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoCD run bash script on Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54985984/gocd-run-bash-script-on-pipeline)

Comment: @AshwanthKumar Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a stupid mistake that i have made. GoCD mentioned it below to the input field.

Basically, If it is multiple arguments, then we need to put that in a new line. So after that, it started working fine.

so in my case, it would be like,

```
build
--configuration=qa
```

Please see screen shot.

[image]